# IE10 navigator.userAgent script doesn't work

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm trying to detect if the browser is IE by not looking for IE browser-centric components but rather looking for navigator.userAgent containing either firefox or chrome. The following script works fine in FF and Chrome but seems to be ignored in IE10.

```
var is_firefox = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1;
var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
if (!is_firefox && !is_chrome) {
    var message = "I'm an IE browser";
} else {
    var message = "I'm not an IE browser";
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have any other error in your code? And why do you want to detect the browser by userAgent?

Comment: No other error messages. Using the userAgent seems to be easiest.

Comment: Sorry the question was not clear, I'm wondering why you want to detect IE? What is the reason you need to know that it is IE?

Comment: Detecting individual browsers is now generally thought of as bad practice - not least because it's impossible to keep track of all the browser/hardware combinations available *now*, much less capabilities of browsers, versions and hardware released in the future. Most developers would encourage you to detect **features** and adapt the site based on those, not based on a specific user agent.

Answer (score 1):

Though I'd rather join the discussion in the comment, I really can't. Just re-created my account. So to answer your question. There is likely a reason that it is failing, and goes to show why testing the `userAgent` is a bad idea.

If you have the Chrome Frame add-on installed, it will add "chromeframe" to the `userAgent` string, which will set `is_chrome` to `true`. If I remember correctly my IE 10 came with Chrome Frame. Write the `userAgent` string to console and see. In almost everyone's honest opinion, using the `userAgent` is just a bad idea, as is browser detection in general, and in the long run may not be the easiest. Once you understand that the `userAgent` string can be modified when add-ons are installed and user's can flat out change them, you realize the work cut out for you.

If you are trying to block or serve content depending on whether the user has IE, it is best to use feature detection or conditional comments. You can use this to set a js variable and then do whatever you need.
Here is an old school way using conditional comments

```
<html>
   <head>
       <!--[if ie 7]>
       <script>var _ie=8;</script>
       <![endif]-->
       <!--[if ie 8]>
       <script>var _ie=8;</script>
       <![endif]-->
       <!--[if ie 9]>
       <script>var _ie=9;</script>
       <![endif]-->
       <script type="text/javascript">
           if(_ie && _ie<9){
              // do something here
              // will not run in any other browser, because _ie is undefined
           }
       </script>
   </head>
```

The drawback to this solution is that it can't be used in external files, so the conditional comments would be on the page and the check could be in either the page itself or the external file. There would be errors, because you check for the existence of the variable first

The simplest way in IE is to check for `ActiveXObject`, as it is proprietary, and is likely not going anywhere. So it is very likely to be future safe.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // test for ie
    var _ie=("ActiveXObject" in window);
</script>
```

Really, this is browser detection by feature detection, so it still goes with the norm, plus it's short and sweet.

You can also refer to this [document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537509.aspx)

Comment: I think conditional comment doesn't work in IE10 and latest than this. Ref: http://www.sitepoint.com/microsoft-drop-ie10-conditional-comments/

Comment: I just tried '!!window.ActiveXObject' and it came back false on IE10, Chrome (latest) and FF (25).

Comment: Ah, sorry, just looked at how I'm handling this on our intranet site. Apparently I changed it to `var_ie=("ActiveXObject" in window)`. I had issues with this when we were prepping for IE10 support, and came across a bunch of issues. I just tested in console: IE10=true, IE8=true,IE7=true, FF(26)=false, Chrome(latest)=false.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking chrome and firefox, why not to check for IE itself.

```
var message;
if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('msie') > -1){
   message = "I'm an IE browser";
} else {
   message = "I'm not an IE browser";
}
alert(message);
```

Edit:====>

Try checking this:

```
navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('trident') > -1
```

Note: TRIDENT is the browser engine used by IE.

Comment: 'navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()' returns nothing like "msie" in it: "mozilla/5.0 (windows nt 6.1; wow64; trident/7.0; slcc2; .net clr 2.0.50727; .net clr 3.5.30729; .net clr 3.0.30729; media center pc 6.0; .net4.0c; .net4.0e; rv:11.0) like gecko"

Comment: ofcourse it returns. But I guess, you are checking this in Mobile Browser.

Comment: Well, I have added code to check browser engine instead of the browser name. This will help you for sure. Good Luck!

Comment: @AshishKumar [New IE does not expose itself as IE anymore:](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2013/09/21/internet-explorer-11-user-agent-string-ua-string-sniffing-compatibility-with-gecko-webkit.aspx)  `[...]User-Agent sniffing has proven to be the top compatibility problem [...] each time a new version of Internet Explorer ships. [...] Many websites would scan for the MSIE token and, if present, return non-standard markup which would not render properly in modern versions of IE. [...]`